# HTTP response code: 403 when attempting AWS auth in Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, emr

I'm having an issue authenticating in Flink using the EC2 role assuming method. The jobs are being submitted via `aws emr add-steps`.

---

The following code works when in the main method and allows me to see the details of my stream.

```
val k = new AmazonKinesisClient(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider())
k.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName("my-region")))
println("Stream: " + k.describeStream("stream-name"))
```

---

However when trying to authenticate on the same EMR cluster using the same methodology I get the following error.

```
val config = new Properties()
config.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, "my-region")
config.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER, "INSTANCE")
config.put(ConsumerConfigConstants.STREAM_INITIAL_POSITION, "LATEST")

val consumer = new FlinkKinesisConsumer[String](
  "stream-name", new SimpleStringSchema, config)
```

Error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.internal.EC2MetadataClient.readResponse(EC2MetadataClient.java:111)
```

---

I also tried altering the AmazonKinesisClient.createKinesisClient method to force the use of the `InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider`. But unfortunately that gives the same 403 error.

```
public static AmazonKinesisClient createKinesisClient(Properties configProps) {
    AmazonKinesisClient client = new AmazonKinesisClient(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider());
    client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName("my-region")));
    return client;
}
```

Error again.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.internal.EC2MetadataClient.readResponse(EC2MetadataClient.java:111)
```

Comment: Do you get an error from `new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials()`?

Comment: If I call ```new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials()``` in the main method it works. If I call new ```InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials()``` in AWSUtil.createKinesisClient I get the 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a proxy to access external resources make sure you add `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts 169.254.169.254` to allow the server to hit the meta data store.